# How can I upload a YouTube video in terminal on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: video, youtube, upload

How can I upload a YouTube video in terminal on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit? I'm asking for a complete tutorial.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Comment: I do not understand . confused. is there a video?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX8xlnk54Mg